# Looking for precompiled binaries of the latest Hunspell for windows

Tags: windows, spell-check

I want to install Hunspell on windows, but on the sourceforge page I find only the sources. There are some binaries too, but they are for only very old versions.

Is there a place where I can find precompiled Windows binaries of the newest version of standalone Hunspell?

Answer (score 2):

I found something here: 
https://github.com/zdenop/hunspell-mingw/downloads with details as below:

```
hunspell-mingw-1.3.2-win32.zip — hunspell 1.3.2 win32 build with cmake and mingw32
1010KB · Uploaded 2 years ago
```

Comment: please don't post a link to provide an answer, post the information yourself, or at least partially, and then use the link as credits/source.

Answer (score 0):

I found this:

http://bigwebideas.com/15e022cd83e431d02428f4af0235fdfa

But I'm not sure if this is the latest version, but it's hosted on sourceforge. I just don't see how to get there from the main page. Check the hashes just in case.

Comment: This is the old version which I mentioned in the quiestion. It was released in April 2008, so it's pretty outdated. It can't handle newer dictionary files.

Comment: The latest binary available is version 1.2.8. I don't think they were ever compiled into binaries after that.

Comment: On the sourceforge site they apparently don't. The question is: is there someone else who makes precompiled windows binaries for hunspell?